# Which method is better for finding max value in sql server?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to find the max salary from table and my table **Employee** contains following data

```
Id  Salary
1   5000
2   4000
3   1000
4   5000
5   2000
6   5000
7   5000
```

Here I can use two method to get max salary,but i don't know which method is better, there are

```
select max(Salary) from Employee
or
select max(distinct Salary) from Employee
```

Please let me know which query is faster and better and why ?

Comment: You can test and find out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without the `DISTINCT`. See [`MAX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187751.aspx):

> DISTINCT is not meaningful with MAX and is available for ISO compatibility only.

If you think about it, what could `DISTINCT` actually mean in this context? You're selecting *one* value - what does it matter whether you saw that value once or 20 times in the group of rows you're looking through for the maximum value?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Wouldn't the sql optimaizer use the same execution plan in both cases?

Comment: @voo - I would expect so, yes. But I'd still advocate not having the word there - all it does (if you're not familiar with SQL) is make you spend time wondering why the original author decided to put it there.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever 100% agree with you, just wanted to make sure about optimization))